# open symbol library for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, uibutton, symbols

Where do I get simple symbols for headers, footers, buttons and so on I could use in iPhone apps?
I'm surprised to not find open symbol libraries for iPhone programmers. I can't imagine, that most of the poor programmers are always designing and creating their own symbols.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sallee Design offers a pack of 80 free png icons:

[Sallee Design - MimiGlyphs](http://salleedesign.com/resources/mimi-glyphs/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Slevin, sorry for the late acception of your answer. I'm still pretty supprized that this topic is so rarely discussed out there. Most of the programmers should need symbols and icons for their apps as well. Is everyone buying stuff or creating it by themselfs...